# Is there any way to set the start line number in IntelliJ / PyCharm / etc.?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to set the start line number to be 0 (rather than 1). In this way, code indexes match the line number in data files which makes debugging easier.
I was wondering if there is any way to do so.

Comment: Line numbers are starting from 1 everywhere. What debugger prints them from 0?

Comment: Yes, but it will be very helpful to have that option. Let's say debugger givers error that line[7] is problematic. When I open the file, I need to make sure I see line #8 since the indexes start from 1. It is very possible to make a mistake specifically if these kinds of observations are frequent.

Comment: What debugger gives you a stacktrace with line numbers start from 0? In IntelliJ IDEA, debugger prints stacks with same line numbers as in Editor